# Ejecutar funcion php en el onclick de un boton

Tags: php, html

Necesito ejecutar el contenido de una `función` de [php](/questions/tagged/php)en el evento `onclick` de un botón, hay alguna manera de realizar esto?

```
<?php
function accion()
   {
     echo "accion";
    }
?>


<input type="submit" name="" value="Buscar" id="boton1" onclick = "">
```

Comment: El código PHP se ejecuta en el servidor; no lograras ejecutar código PHP en el navegador del cliente.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dependerá de lo que realice en la función dentro de `PHP` , o el valor que retorna dicha función. en este caso su ejemplo realiza un `echo` y  retorna un valor("accion") pero sin las comillas respectivas para tomarlo como una cadena en `JavaScript` , por eso es necesario añadirlas antes de imprimir el valor de la función dentro de `Javascript`. si no se necesitara un valor cadena , se le quitaría las comillas antes del `echo` dentro `Javascript`.

```
<?php
  function accion(){
    echo "accion";
  }
  function acciondos(){
    echo 19;
  }
?>

<input type="submit" name="" value="Buscar" id="boton1" onclick = "funcion();">
<script>
  function funcion(){
    alert('<?php echo accion(); ?>');
    alert(<?php echo acciondos(); ?>);
    /* Escribir en el Documento*/
    document.write('<?php echo accion(); ?>');
    document.write(<?php echo acciondos(); ?>);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: y si lo que deseo es que escriba en el documento?

Comment: @josemarquez `document.write` , actualicé mi respuesta.

Comment: si quisiera enviar un parametro a la función como haría? si es que el valor del input deberia ir en el parametro

Comment: Funciona si en document.write le añado mas el include o require?

Comment: Lo que pasa tengo el archivo separado.
Para ello deberia poner alert('<?php include './matematicas.php'; echo accion(); ?>');

Answer (score 3):

Creo que depende de la acción de vayas a hacer, en ese caso si lo hacer por el evento onclick puedes hacer un llamado ajax a un archivo php.

```
//asi queda el archivo que llama
<input type="submit" name="" value="Buscar" id="boton1" onclick = "accion();">
<script>
    function accion()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST', //aqui puede ser igual get
            url: 'funciones/mifuncion.php',//aqui va tu direccion donde esta tu funcion php
            data: {id:1,otrovalor:'valor'},//aqui tus datos
            success:function(data){
                //lo que devuelve tu archivo mifuncion.php
           },
           error:function(data){
            //lo que devuelve si falla tu archivo mifuncion.php
           }
         });
    }
</script>

//y el archivo mifuncion.php
<?php
//mi accion
echo "accion";
?>
```

Comment: Y como hago eso? tienes algún documento o videotutorial el cual me ayude a realizar el llamado ajax....

Comment: @josemarquez actualize mi respuesta espero te sea de ayuda a lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Hola, como podría hacer para configurar una sesion basado en este mismo ejemplo? estoy generando una lista y deseo actualizar una sesion basado el <li> al cual se hace click puesto que al generarse cada uno tiene nombre diferente